# Receiving email from alias - sendmail

Tags: email, sendmail, alias

I have setted up sendmail on my CentOS server with webmin installed. I've added a few important mail aliases such as this:

```
administrator@mywebsite.com  -> to ->  myhotmail.com
```

Now when I send an email to `administrator@mywebsite.com`, I get no email in my hotmail inbox, it's been a few hours with no email yet.

How come this isn't working? I can send emails to my hotmail inbox via a PHP script from the server but I cannot send email and get it forwarded by the alias email?

I looked in the `/var/log/maillog` and I don't see any errors there. What can be happening?

Before you answer, sendmail *is* running.

Hotmail has responded the email that I just sent earlier:

```
This is an automatically generated Delivery Status Notification.

Unable to deliver message to the following recipients, due to being unable to connect successfully to the destination mail server.

      administrator@mywebsite.com



Reporting-MTA: dns;blu0-omc4-s19.blu0.hotmail.com
Received-From-MTA: dns;BLU0-SMTP153
Arrival-Date: Fri, 1 Jul 2011 10:39:43 -0700

Final-Recipient: rfc822;administrator@mywebsite.com
Action: failed
Status: 4.4.7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sendmail cannot read directly the **/etc/aliases** file, so every time you make changes to it, you must run the *newaliases* command to update the database. Maybe you forgot to do that?

Comment: I'm sure webmin does that already, I ran that command and made a new email and still nothing in my inbox.

Comment: Hm, is your sendmail configured to accept mails for *mywebsite.com*? It works with system account by default, not sure if Webmin does anything to fix that.